# How do you move files but not the directories in hdfs?

Tags: shell, hadoop, directory, hdfs

I've been trying to find the solution to this problem for a while. I have found that in a normal file system using shell you can use this command to move all files under a location but leave the directories alone.

```
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} destination_path \;
```

I was wondering if there is also a command to be able to do the same in hdfs.

So if I have a folder in hdfs called "folder1" which contains the files "copyThis.txt", "copyThisAsWell.txt" and "theFinalCopy.txt" and also contains a folder "doNotCopy" and I want to copy the files into a new folder called "folder2" but leave the folder "doNotCopy" behind, how can this be done in hdfs?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: As far i know there is no similar command so far in hdfs to do this. I could suggest using hadoop fs -cp *.txt folder2/ so that you could copy all *.txt files omitting the folder

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct hdfs command to achieve this. But you can still do it by using combination of unix & hdfs commands. Something like this:

```
hdfs dfs -ls folder1 | grep "^-" | awk '{print $8}' | awk '{system("hdfs dfs -cp "$0" folder2")}'
```

**Explanation:**

`hdfs dfs -ls folder1` : list the parent directory (not recursively)

`grep "^-"` : Exclude directories from the list

`awk '{print $8}'` : Print just the file name to be copied

`awk '{system("hdfs dfs -cp "$0" folder2")}'` : execute hdfs command with the file name just fetched

**Note:** This is just a workaround and will not work if you want to specify the depth like `-maxdepth` option of `find` command.

Answer (score 1):

With xargs: 
hdfs dfs -ls folder1 | grep "^-" | awk '{print $8}' | xargs -n 1 -P 2 -I % hdfs dfs -mv % folder2